# How to create geom_text and geom_point with matching manual color scales?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'd like to create a plot where my labels (derived from `geom_text`) match a manual color scale I'm using for my points. Here's an example using the Iris data set. When I enter the following code I get this error:

```
library(tidyverse)

labels <- tibble(
           Species = c("setosa", "veriscolor", "virginica"),
           Sepal.Length = c(4.3, 5.5, 7), 
           Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 2.3, 3.7))

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Species)) +
  geom_text(data = labels, 
            aes(x = Sepal.Length, 
                y = Sepal.Width, label = Species, color = Species),
            inherit.aes = F) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gray", "purple", "orange")    

Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 4 needed but only 3 provided.
```

I've seen that this has something to do with unused factor levels but I can't seem to apply their solutions here.

Comment: In your example one of your factor labels in your created dataset is mis-spelled ("verginica" vs "virginica") so you have four levels instead of three.  To avoid spelling mistakes you could do something like `Species = unique(iris$Species)`.  You should check for a similar problem in your actual datasets.  If this isn't the problem there you should update the question to make it match your real situation better.

Comment: `veriscolor` is also a missspelling. There also shouldn't be a space in `Sepal. Width`.

Comment: My bad--the issue is that I work on properity systems that don't connect to the open internet, so I have to hand type all my code.  I'll fix it.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in your example except by the mispelling in species names. Change to `c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")` and your example runs perfectly. If you're having the same error message in your work, it's likely that you have something similar there. Use `unique()` to check the entries in your data and see if it's agree with your labels. 
If the problem persists, update the question with a more specific example. I understand that you're working with proprietary data, but try to mimic the data structure that you have instead of using any data sets that come with R.

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta, oy, that IS embarrassing . . . but I can't delete it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not in ggplot, but in your labels data frame:

```
labels <-
  data.frame(
    Species = levels(iris$Species),
    Sepal.Length = c(4.3, 5.5, 7), 
    Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 2.3, 3.7) )
```

You can also specify color in the global aes to simplify your code. And following [Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor) comment, you don't need to specify x and y in geom_text, since it's also in the global aesthetics.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(data = labels, aes(label = Species)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("gray", "purple", "orange"))
```

[image]

Comment: With the `x` and `y` set globally, you only need to specify `label` in the `geom_text` layer.

Comment: Thanks, this is great.  For my understanding, is the issue that ggplot "considered" the species in my label set and the species in the iris set different because one was strings and the other was factors?

Comment: No, the problem was that you misspelled the species names in your labels set, so ggplot understood it as different species from the iris data. By using `Species = levels(iris$Species)` or anything similar you just avoid typing errors.

Comment: And as pointed by the site community, since it was a typing error, it's better to delete this question, as it provides little help for other users.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  I'm using the `iris` data set as an example as my code is on my client's system and I can't upload it here.  There were no misspellings in the original code.